# RequireJS in the browser: how can I log a variable without modifying my code first?

Tags: javascript, debugging, console, requirejs, js-amd

I'm using RequireJS in my browser. I have some JS loaded by a script tag, something like:

```
requirejs(["jquery", "shared", function($, shared) {
  var foo='bar';
}
```

I would like to print the current value of 'foo' from a JS console in the Chrome Dev Tools. How can I do this?

**Edit 2:** This question was originally very vaguely worded - sorry about that. To clarify, I do not wish to stop using RequireJS, pollute global, or know in advance what it is I want to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in Chrome or Firebug to break at the point of your closure. Foo will then be available to the console until you resume script execution.

**edit:** Scope will still matter. If the variable is private within a member of shared, you'll need to set a break in shared.js instead, e.g. if we assume shared.js contains:

```
var shared = {
    myFunc: function() {
        var foo = 'bar';
        // break here
    }
}
```

Comment: By 'I do not wish to know in advance what it is I want to investigate' I mean I want the ability to print, run or do anything I want in scope of the require module, without knowing in advance what it is I would like to debug. Many of the answers here have included making globals of anything I'd like to investigate - that's obviously not a solution.

Comment: I don't believe variables created in the RequireJS callbacks have "scope in the require module". They are anonymous (lambda) callback functions, and the scope ends when the function ends. That's why a variable in a higher scope is used for storing values for later inspection, or more properly for development (as @hedgehog pointed out) a breakpoint is added to inspect the running code. After the code is finished running, the scope is gone, and because it was an anonymous callback the variable state is not stored as part of the RequireJS object.

Comment: @thirdender Somewhat off topic, you're using quotes to imply something I haven't said - the full quote is 'I want the ability to print, run or do anything I want in scope of the require module'. Can you please fix your comment? Thanks.

Comment: @nailer, sorry, I don't have the ability to edit the original comment any longer or I'd remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, the whole point of using RequireJS is not to use global variables!

Therefore I define a `console.js` module like this:

```js
define(function() {
  var nativeConsole = {};
  try {
    // for IE 8/9
    if (!window.console) {
      window.console = {
        log:   function() {},
        debug: function() {},
        info:  function() {},
        warn:  function() {},
        error: function() {}
      };
    }
    nativeConsole = console;
  // Firefox throws an exception if you access the console object and it doesn't exist. Wow!
  } catch (e) { }
  return nativeConsole;
});
```

Then use it like this:

```js
requirejs(["jquery", "console", function($, console) {
  var foo='bar';
  console.warn("foo = " + foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with

```
`requirejs(["jquery", "shared", function($, shared) {   
  var foo=bar;
  console.debug(foo);
}`
```

The same command works in Firefox too.

Comment: Assuming this is the right answer, I usually do `window.console && console.log(...)` when outputting debug information. It ensures that the code won't fail in browsers that don't have a console. The debug lines should still be removed when the code goes live, but it helps if someone in management happens to look at your code with the "wrong browser", or manages to make your code go live earlier than planned...

Comment: @reporter: As the question mentions, I wish to define foo in the script, but print it from the JS console. Your answer shows the variable being defined and it being printed immediately afterwards.

Comment: I see I did misunderstand your question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The JS Console already has the context of your page. Just open the console, type "foo", then press Enter.

Comment: That likely won't work, as the variable `foo` only exists within that closure.

Comment: @Rajesh: that doesn't work: 'console.log(foo)' returns
'ReferenceError: foo is not defined'

Comment: Ah, yes. Closures. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Move the var definition outside of the closure.

```
var foo;
requirejs(["jquery", "shared", function($, shared) {
  foo='bar';
});
```

The downside to this is that `foo` now exists in the global `window` scope (the variable exists as `window.foo`), and global variables should be avoided. It can be helpful for debugging though. Alternatively, just define it to `window` as such:

```
requirejs(["jquery", "shared", function($, shared) {
  window.foo='bar';
});
```

Or, if you plan to do this and keep the variable around past the debugging stage, you should consider creating a custom namespace for "your" variables.

```
var myNamespace = {};
requirejs(["jquery", "shared", function($, shared) {
  myNamespace.foo='bar';
});
```

And then you can `window.console && console.log(myNamespace.foo)`.

Comment: With the custom namespace, it's important to use a separate namespace for each at least each file. The risk is that in a large codebase, there will be multiple closures using the same name for a variable, and then you have the same problem as with global variables. Increasing scope of a variable for debugging is never a good idea.

Comment: @thirdender I get that not using require (by moving the variable outside) would allow me to print it, the purpose of the exercise is to allow me to debug the app without changing it, knowing in advance what I'd like to print, or removing the advantages of require (ie, polluting global or using alternative namespace systems). Thanks for your answer though!